# How to extract an AES key which resides in a TR-31 keyblock

Tags: key-exchange

I have a version D TR-31 keyblock (which contains an AES Key for use in CMAC), and have the ZCMK key used, what is the method which I can use to extract the key from the TR-31 keyblock? I'll do my own development.

Answer (score 0):

This is specified in the TR-31 specification, namely ASC X9 TR 31-2018, Interoperable Secure Key Exchange Key Block Specification.

It is copyrighted so I cannot provide a better answer.

You can buy the document at [the ANSI web store](https://webstore.ansi.org/standards/ascx9/ascx9tr312018).

Answer (score 0):

As another answer mentioned the standard is copyright unfortunately.

However there are open source implementions of TR-31 that can be used to learn how TR-31 works.

https://github.com/openemv/tr31

https://github.com/chhil/TR31Keyblock

Note also that TR-31 had been superseded with a nearly identical standard named ANSI X9.143.

See https://webstore.ansi.org/standards/ascx9/ansix91432022

The only difference in practice appears to be the mandate for key length obfuscation padding for AES and TDES keys.